# Unable to update GTM Variable using Google API

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-tag-manager

Using "Try it!" feature from GTM API documentation:
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v1/reference/accounts/containers/variables/list?authuser=2
I am able to get a list with my variables from GTM

However, when i try to update a variable (https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v1/reference/accounts/containers/variables/update?authuser=2), again using "Try it!", i get:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidArgument",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

I'm pretty sure i insert all the parameters correctly, and after one day of trying i assume that there's something wrong with GTM's Update Variable API.

Can somebody confirm that updating a GTM variable works for them ?

Also i try to do this from back-end and the same response pops-up.

Here is my code:

```
   public void Authenticate()
{


    string serviceAccountEmail = "xxxxxxxxxxxx@local-proj.iam.gserviceaccount.com";

    string folder = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/App_Data/MyGoogleStorage/key.p12");
    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(folder, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

    ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
       new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
       {
           Scopes = new[] { TagManagerService.Scope.TagmanagerEditContainers}
       }.FromCertificate(certificate));

    // Create the service.
    var service = new TagManagerService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "My Local Proj"
    });
```

At this point service is authenticated, so i can simply do:

```
var myGTMVars = service.Accounts.Containers.Variables.List("AccountID", "ContainerID").Execute();
```

To get all my variables from GTM from back-end. Everything works as expected.

But when i try to update one:

```
    Variable gTMVar = new Variable();
    gTMVar.Name = "IsAfterSignUpSuccess";
    gTMVar.Type = "c";
    var param = new Parameter()
    {
        Type = "template",
        Value = "true"
    };
    gTMVar.Parameter = new List<Parameter>();
    gTMVar.Parameter.Add(param);
    try
    {
        var newVar = service.Accounts.Containers.Variables.Update(body: gTMVar, accountId: "xxx", containerId: "xxx", variableId: "x").Execute();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

it fails every time giving me BadRequest. I tried different parameters, different type for variables and nothing helped. Also tried different scopes to init the service - nothing helped.

There's poor information on the subject especially for c#.

I posted my code here - hopefully will save somebody's day as it was not straight forward to authenticate a service from back-end without user interaction. (well in the end it turned out to be easy)

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am having a similar problem with the awct tag, while every settings and parameter is exactly right, it stills return 400 Bad Request, in custom html it works great, I have copied exactly the setup recommended in the dictionary, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I eventually gave up on this integrations, as i understood that it's mostly for managing the container itself rather than sanding an event or something from the back-end.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update the value, parameter in your request has to have 3 properties:
type: THE TYPE YOU ARE TRYING TO EDIT,
key: value,
value: YOUR VALUE

URL: https://www.googleapis.com/tagmanager/v1/accounts/accountId/containers/containerId/variables/variableId
PARAMETERS:

```
{
  "name":"YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME",
  "type":"YOUR_VARIABLE_TYPE", 
  "parameter":[{
      "type":"YOUR_TYPE",
      "key":"value",
      "value":"YOUR_VALUE"
   }]
}
```

Documentation for Tag Manager API has omissions and there is very little help available out there. 
Most guides focus on the GUI and Simo Ahava mostly uses Python in his examples.

Best,
Cika